# HTML Video pause, play and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I trying to create an ad banner, when the page loads the ad banner plays. The ad banner also has a play and pause button function, i.e, when you click the play/pause function the video plays and pauses. Once the Video has finished play the `<div class="vid-banner"></div>` changes class and is replace with an image. I am not the greatest at Jquery,  the link Below is a short snippet of the direction i am going in.

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/13cmpz8a/1/)

```
$("#play-pause-btn").click, '#video-wall__content'(function(e){
    var video = $(this).get(0);
    if (video.pause === false){
        video.pause();
    } else {
        video.play();
    }

    return false;
});
```

});

P.S if anyone know how this can be preformed using angular JS please provide me with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvfzcdna/4/)

The issue I see you are having here is with video events.

I've used the html5 video attribute **paused**, (*pause* is the method to pause the video) to trigger the button click.

It is unnecessary to add the onclick attribute on

```
<a id="play-pause-btn" onClick="playPause">click me</a>
```

since you are already triggering the click event using its id attribute

full JS:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video-wall__content"); 
$("#play-pause-btn").click(function(e){
    if(video.paused==true){
        console.log('video paused');
        //display banner on video stopping
        video.play();
    }else{
        //hide banner
        console.log('video played');
        video.pause();
    }
});
video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    console.log('video completed');
    //display banner on video ending
});
```

Take a look at [media events reference list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to get the most out of video events